# How to change default directory for a vsftpd to a virtualhost folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ftp, vsftpd

I have configured multiple virtual hosts in Apache in **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. I am creating users with `useradd <username>`. I want to assign the directory of the virtual host to a specific user in vsftpd. For example, when the user log in with an FTP client, the only access he need to have is to the folder where the content of their virtual host is locate; for example: the home directory for user **john** will be `/var/www/example.com/` and you will not have access to any other.

I also want restrict ssh access to root users and make available port 21 for ftp users. Port 21 is already open.

This is my **vsftpd.conf** file:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Which the Ubuntu Server **version**?

Comment: @jluizsouzadev 20.04 LTS

Comment: For **ftp** users **only the port 21 available**, right?

Comment: Copy and paste the file content **"/etc/vsftpd.conf"** on your post.

Comment: @jluizsouzadev done

Comment: Can you install [nmap](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-nmap-check-linux-open-ports/) package on Ubuntu server and then run as **root** user the following command **"nmap -P0 SERVER_IP"** and to post the output on your post? Tha one's to know what the **ports status** on the server.

Answer (score 0):

For restricting users to go up to upper level folder you need to set chroot jail, and from the configuration file the chroot jail seems to be set, on line:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

For limiting access to specific users you probably want to check the following directives:

```
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
```

and

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
```